# How to add Flags set to '1 'for a given condition using Oracle Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a school table and In the below query I am setting up the Flag column as 1 for studentsID, location with attendanceDt >= 20 and year >=2019 and student type as primary.

Could anyone please suggest how to add the flags '1' in the RESULT OUTPUT  and return the expected results by refining the below query:-

```
Select studentID,location,TO_CHAR('attendanceDt','yyyymm') as attendancedate,count(attendanceDt) as Total,1 as Flag from SchoolTable a
where TO_CHAR('attendanceDt','yyyy')>= 2019 and a.studenttype = 'primary'
Having count(attendanceDt)>=20
group by studentID,location,TO_CHAR('attendanceDt','yyyymm');
```

**RESULT OUTPUT:**

```
studentID  location attendanceDt    Total Flag
100         Australia  201908         20   1
101         Australia  201908         21   1 
102         USA        201902         27   1
103         Canada     201901         22   1
102         USA        201902         24   1
103         USA        201902         25   1
```

I need to refine the above Oracle query to return the results by summing the flags which are =1 where attendanceDt >= 20 corresponding to location and attendance dates.Below is the expected output:-

**Expected Output**

```
location attendanceDt  Count(Flag)
Australia  201908          2
USA        201902          3
Canada     201901          1
```

Comment: Don't tag spam. If you are using SQL, tag the RDBMS you are using and **only** tag that one. I have removed all the conflicting tags; please tag properly.

Comment: @Lamu I will appreciate for constructive comments as I am a new user in stack overflow, please suggest if you have a clue for the above query.I am working on Oracle so tagged relevant to Oracle .

Comment: `TO_CHAR('attendanceDt','yyyymm')` returns an error, not a result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select x.location,x.attendancedate,count(x.Flag)t_count from
  ( 
       Select studentID,location,
     TO_CHAR('attendanceDt','yyyymm') as attendancedate,
     count(attendanceDt) as Total,1 as Flag 
     from SchoolTable a
     where TO_CHAR('attendanceDt','yyyy')>= 2019 and a.studenttype = 'primary'
     Having count(attendanceDt)>=20
      group by studentID,location,TO_CHAR('attendanceDt','yyyymm')
 )x group by x.location,x.attendancedate;
```

You can try something like that

Comment: when I add countdistinct(x.Flag)t_count in your above query it throws error.Is there a way how I can return distinct count of the flag in your query.Please suggest

Comment: Could you please show the error you have got